# How to send "Ctrl + C" event to a Qt widget?

Tags: events, qt

I want to a "Ctrl+C" event to a Qt widget, say a QLineEdit when the person presses the copy icon of my application. How should I do it ? Will it make QLineEdit do what it does when a user specifically presses "Ctrl + C" (i.e. copy) ?

Just a clarification : The widget may not be QLineEdit. In one of the cases, its is QWebView. Now, it displays a Web page, in which there may be text fields of its own. I want to paste something on those text fields. That is only possible if those text fields embedded inside the web page feel that the user has presses "Ctrl+V".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QCoreApplication::postEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) with two [QKeyEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qkeyevent.html)s (QEvent::KeyPress and 
QEvent::KeyRelease)

Answer (score 0):

```
    QKeyEvent * evt = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::Type::KeyPress, Qt::Key_C, Qt::ControlModifier); 
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(target_widget, evt);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @MukulKant why did you delete. This is a valid answer.